# Print data in table using for loop in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

After successfully fetching API data, the result looks like this:

```js
{
  fred: {
    foo: bar,
    baz: qux,
    fred: xzzy
  },
  thud: {
    foo: bar,
    baz: qux,
    fred: xzzy
  },
  plugh: {
    foo: bar,
    baz: qux,
    fred: xzzy
  }
}
```

I need to display the data in the table as follows:

```
th th 
fred bar xzzy
thud bar xzzy
plugh bar xzzy
```

Using the code below, I've only acommplished the `<tr>`:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<tr v-for="(values, key) in object" v-bind:key="key.id">
  <th scope="row">{{ key }}</th>
  <td v-for="(values, key) in object" v-bind:key="values.id">{{ values.last }}</td>
</tr>
```

Which prints as follows:

```
th th 
fred bar bar bar
thud qux qux qux
plugh xzzy xzzy xzzy
```

Would also be grateful if referenced to a good nested arrays/objects tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    exampleObject: {
      "fred": {
        "foo": "bar",
        "baz": "qux",
        "fred": "xzzy"
      },
      "thud": {
        "foo": "bar",
        "baz": "qux",
        "fred": "xzzy"
      },
      "plugh": {
        "foo": "bar",
        "baz": "qux",
        "fred": "xzzy"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="(values, key) in exampleObject" v-bind:key="key">
      <th scope="row">{{ key }}</th>
      <td v-for="(val, keyCol) in values" v-if="keyCol != 'baz'" v-bind:key="keyCol">{{ val }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The same example but on codepen:
https://codepen.io/fabiogarcia/pen/poyprYw

Comment: error  The 'values' variable inside 'v-for' directive should be replaced with a computed property that returns filtered array instead. You should not mix 'v-for' with 'v-if'  vue/no-use-v-if-with-v-for

Answer (score 0):

Try like it:

```
<tr v-for="(valuesParent, key) in object" v-bind:key="valuesParent">
  <th scope="row">{{ key }}</th>
  <td v-for="(values, key) in valuesParent" v-bind:key="values">{{ values }}</td>
</tr>
```